# How do I NOT print the variable if the value is zero?

Tags: php, sql

Currently I am using this piece of code ( with help from these forums )

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultbline))

{
$var1 = $row['prod_selectname'] . "0"; 
$var2 = $row['prod_selectname'] . "6";
$var3 = $row['prod_selectname'] . "11";
$var4 = $row['prod_selectname'] . "18";
$var5 = $row['prod_selectname'] . "t";
$var6 = $row['prod_selectname'] . "24";
$var7 = $row['prod_selectname'] . "36";
$vartrtot = $$var1+$$var2+$$var3+$$var4+$$var5+$$var6+$$var7;
if ($vartrtot>0) {
$messageb .="<tr><td>"
        . $row['prod_name']
        . "</td><td>" . $vartrtot . "</td><td></td>
        <td>" . $$var1 . "</td>
        <td>" . $$var2 . "</td>
        <td>" . $$var3 . "</td>
        <td>" . $$var4 . "</td>
        <td>" . $$var5 . "</td>
        <td>" . $$var6 . "</td>
        <td>" . $$var7 . "</td>
";}
}
```

These value are generated from drop down select menus.

I have a small problem where if no option is selected on the drop down, the output from this table prints a zero where I dont want it to print anything?

So how can I say :
if $$var4 = 0; then dont print anything in that space.
if $$var5 = 0; then dont print anything in that space.
etc.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am not getting your requirement. Why have you concatenated values in the while loop..

Comment: prod_selectname can be 1 of over 100 flavours, and the 0,6,12 etc are the strength.
So on the 1 line of the form there will be multiple dropdown menus for the client to choose the strengths of that liquid.
The only data retrieved from the database is the name of the liquid.
I hope you understand.
(I am a newbie)

Comment: what are you trying to store in $vartrtot

Comment: Saurabh, $vartrtot is just the total of the 7 variables above.

Ive just tried this, but no joy

<td>" . if( $$var1 != 0  $$var1 . "</td>

Its showing errors

Comment: i am not sure why are you trying to add strings.. they are not integers..

Comment: Im not too sure myself. I just thought all variables had a $ before them ? And that code was suggested, with thanks, from people on here.
It is all working anyhow. Its just that the everything I am trying either outputs NULL or 0. I just want it to not print NULL or 0

Comment: try remoing $ from $$var1 and so on. so use only 1 $ for variables and see ifi it works..

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your input BEFORE querying then. If someone doesn't select something from a drop down, you should show an error and not even query the database!

Something in the form of:

```
if(!is_numeric($_POST['wathever_field'])){
    $errors[] = 'You must select a value from wathever dropdown';
}

if(count($errors) == 0){
    //Do my querying!
}
```

And then later in your script, print out the errors to the screen.

Comment: Hi, they are not errors that is outputting, its just outputting the value 0, whereas I dont want it to output the 0, it should just be left blank.

the dropdowns are also dynamic from the database so not sure the your code above would work ?

ie
`echo "<td width=\"65\">"; if ($row["boption06"] == 1)
echo "<select name=\"orderdetails[" . $row['prod_selectname'] . 06 . "]\" id=\"" . $row['prod_selectname'] . 06 . "\"> $liquidoptions </select>"; 
echo "</td>";`

Comment: I can't fix your code for you, you have to understand what you are trying to achieve. We are giving you hints as to how to fix your issues, not fixing it for you...

Comment: I am trying to understand, Im just starting to learn php.
Im thankfull for the hints but just dont get it yet :(

Comment: Then you may want to use a tutoring service as this site is more for broad questions and answers, not for learning. SO is all about gathering questions and answers that can be reused! Search for PHP Tutoring services on Google, i'm sure you'll find one!

Comment: Yes, I asked a question via the "ASK A QUESTION" button, and I didnt get the answer I needed to help me..... All I got was a "Hint" ?

Comment: So what is the point of this site then ?

I see a "ASK A QUESTION" button at the top, which suggests I can ask a question.
But you are saying its not for learning ?
So why would people need to "Ask a question" if they know everything there is to know ?
I dont get it :?

Comment: Read the FAQ please, i'm not responding anymore